# Do shares purchased on FTSE AIM move with company to other markets?

Tags: united-kingdom, stock-exchanges, stock-markets

I've struggled to find an answer for this so apologies if there is one easily found out there.

At the moment I'm looking at potential investments in the FTSE AIM market, I've read a lot about how some companies have had great success and moved onto the bigger markets when they are ready or need higher bands of funding.
I believe (from what I've read) that once you purchase a share in a company you own that share of the business, even if they de-list.

Firstly, is that accurate? Secondly and the real question here, what happens to the stock you've purchased on the AIM market if they moved to another market?
E.g. does it transfer with the company and continue to grow, do you have to sell and re-invest etc. Fairly new to the markets so I may have mis-interpreted some of the information I've come across so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any shares you buy when a company is listed on one market will remain yours if the company moves to another market.

Markets and exchanges like AIM are just venues for dealing in shares - indeed you can deal in those shares anywhere else that will allow you as well as on the AIM. The benefit of being listed in a market is that trade in the shares will be more "liquid" - there's more likely to be people who want to buy and sell them at any given time.

The bigger concern would be what happens if the company does badly and drops out of the AIM entirely. You'd still be able to sell your shares to any willing buyer, but finding that buyer might get harder.